# how to set datasource in jqGrid

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

i am trying to use jqGrid and i'm getting a fatal error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid
> data source name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\psnm\grid\grid.php:8 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\psnm\grid\grid.php(8): PDO->__construct('localhost', 'root', '') #1
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\psnm\electionadmin.php(40):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\psnm\grid\grid.php on line 8

and line 8 of `grid.php` is

```
$conn = new PDO("localhost",root,"");
```

i have the server at `localhost` my database name is `psnm`, user is `root` and no password, can anybody please help me find out the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of the PDO needs the dsn as the first parameter. Look the syntax below:

```
PDO::__construct() ( string $dsn [, string $username [, string $password [, array $driver_options ]]] )
```

Please consult PHP [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) for more information.